# IIS VS 2008 / Web.config - wrong date format

Tags: asp.net, iis, globalization

can anyone help. I have recently moved servers, its IIS7 rather that our previous IIS6 but everything else is the same, i have set the region to the UK and all date formats plus system local .. I mean everything ..

But when a webpage asp.net is running on IIS7 it thinks the dates are another format..

This is really puzzling .. i did manage to fix it by putting in each web.config

```
    <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

but i have to put it in everyone.. I know i can aslo put it in machine.config.

But i don't understand it, my other server works without modifications. I have checked the web.config and the machine.config on my old server and it has none of these additions

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have also ticked the box in Regional and Language Options (Advanced tab) to say "Apply all settings to the default user profile. The account that .Net runs under will remain as US unless you do this. Reboot.

Been there :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the localization options on the box and see what it is set for--someone probably just selected en-US for the setup and forgot to tell anyone.

Comment: Perhaps trying to reinstall .NET might solve things if .NET was installed pre-correction of the region issue.